# How to prove the existence of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]
I solved this problem for a few specific vectors but I don't know how to prove this in general?
Grateful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First, try to write $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ as linear combination of a basis of $\Bbb{R}^2.$

Comment: Can you give another hint ?

Comment: Try using the scalar product of u with the vector {v1,v2,v3}, then try to manipulate the vector (u.v1)v1 + (u.v2)v2 + (u.v3)v3 - that is the vectors v1, v2, and v3 scaled by the scalar products u.v1, etc. . Hint - take the scalar product of u expressed as s1v1 + s2v2 + s3v3 with the previous vector and figure out what s1,s2,and s3 must be. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Waving away degenerate cases, the four points $u_i$ either form a convex quadrilateral, or one of the $u_i$ lies in the interior of the triangle formed by the other three. In any case the point $u$ lies in a triangle formed by three of the four $u_i$.

This problem deals with an instance of [Caratheodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)) on convex hulls of $> d+1$ points in ${\mathbb R}^d$.